# Spring boot request interceptor and thread local

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thread-local

I am working on a spring boot application in which I have to add an attribute to the root level of every JSON request. This will cost me to change every service manually to adjust the new variable. I am thinking a way around that if I intercept the request and fetch that attribute's value and set it in a ThreadLocal variable so that I can get the variable later within the execution scope of that request later. Is it possible with spring as I am confused with this image
[image: Request Scope]
How the Spring will behave to my hack in this scenario as the web application is too big to change it manually.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: The image is about Spring MVC as I understand. Nothing to do with spring boot

Comment: The basic structure is same according to my understanding, if not then what is your take on this scenario?

Comment: Need more deails about your setup, but the picture you show is irrelevant to what you're asking

Comment: The scope of a request is from request till response and I will make a ThreadLocal Variable at the very beginning so will it persist till the end or it will override because of spring's internal scope handling. that is what I am asking. This diagram is reliant with respect to this scenario

Comment: why does it need to be a ThreadLocal? If it has a different value for each request it should be request scoped. If not it can be a simple variable.

Comment: Do you want to change the body of the request or just add a value to the request? If so, you can do `request.setAttribute("param",value)`. No need for ThreadLocal.

Comment: Cyril and Christian thank you for your interest. Actually the project was converted from Play framework to Spring that is why most of the things are not exactly what spring facilitate. I definitely wanna go with variable scope for each request but my service layer is not a spring component and I can't make it so technically multiple requests can access the service layer functions at a single instance. Anyway I have implemented the threadlocal and by far its good. I hope this solution works.

Comment: Hi @AreebGillani can you post your answer here? facing the same issue as yours. thanks!

Comment: Question from years ago, but for those whom also want to know the answer. Check https://dzone.com/articles/an-alternative-approach-to-threadlocal-using-sprin-1!